# How to create a new column based on a condition in another column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, numpy

In pandas, How can I create a new column `B` based on a column `A` in `df`, such that:

- `B=1` if `A_(i+1)-A_(i) > 5` or `A_(i) <= 10`
- `B=0` if `A_(i+1)-A_(i) <= 5`

However, the first `B_i` value is always one

Example:

| A | B |
| --- | --- |
| 5 | 1 (the first B_i) |
| 12 | 1 |
| 14 | 0 |
| 22 | 1 |
| 20 | 0 |
| 33 | 1 |

Comment: What should we do about last row? Should we assume that A_(i+1) is 0? Or we are calculating value for each B at row 'i+1' instead of "i"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was little confused with your rows numeration bacause we should have missing value on last row instead of first if we calcule for `B_i` basing on condition `A_(i+1)-A_(i)` (first row should have both, `A_(i)` and `A_(i+1)` and last row should be missing `A_(i+1)` value.

Anyway,basing on your example i assumed that we calculate for `B_(i+1)`.

```py
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame(columns=["A"],data=[5,12,14,22,20,33])
df['shifted_A'] = df['A'].shift(1) #This row can be removed - it was added only show to how shift works on final dataframe
df['B']=''
df.loc[((df['A']-df['A'].shift(1))>5) + (df['A'].shift(1)<=10), 'B']=1 #Update rows that fulfill one of conditions with 1
df.loc[(df['A']-df['A'].shift(1))<=5, 'B']=0 #Update rows that fulfill condition with 0
df.loc[df.index==0, 'B']=1 #Update first row in B column
print(df)
```

That prints:

```
    A  shifted_A  B
0   5        NaN  1
1  12        5.0  1
2  14       12.0  0
3  22       14.0  1
4  20       22.0  0
5  33       20.0  1
```

I am not sure if it is fastest way, but i guess it should be one of easier to understand.

#### Little explanation:

`df.loc[mask, columnname]=newvalue` allows us to update value in given column if condition (mask) is fulfilled

`(df['A']-df['A'].shift(1))>5) + (df['A'].shift(1)<=10)`
Each condition here returns True or False. If we added them the result is True if any of that is True (which is simply OR). In case we need AND we can multiply the conditions

Answer (score 3):

Use [`diff`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.diff.html) with a comparison to your value and convertion from boolean to int using [`le`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.le.html):

```
N = 5
df['B'] = (~df['A'].diff().le(N)).astype(int)
```

*NB. using a `le(5)` comparison with inversion enables to have 1 for the first value*
output:

```
    A  B
0   5  1
1  12  1
2  14  0
3  22  1
4  20  0
5  33  1
```

updated answer, simply combine a second condition with OR (`|`):

```
df['B'] = (~df['A'].diff().le(5)|df['A'].lt(10)).astype(int)
```

output: same as above with the provided data

Comment: Thanks for your reply! Could you please check the change on the conditions I have conducted!

Comment: @Jackmath IIUC, see update, this is quite trivial and doesn't change the output here

Answer (score 1):

Use [`Series.diff`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.diff.html), replace first missing value for `1` after compare for greater or equal by [`Series.ge`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.ge.html):

```
N = 5
df['B'] = (df.A.diff().fillna(N).ge(N) | df.A.lt(10)).astype(int)
print (df)
    A  B
0   5  1
1  12  1
2  14  0
3  22  1
4  20  0
5  33  1
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply! Could you please check the change on the conditions I have just conducted!